# Is Power Split affected by status raising/lowering moves?

Tags: pokemon-series

If your opponent uses something like Belly Drum before you use Power Split, will the calculation average the boosted stat or the original stat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Power_Split_(move)):

> Power Split will ignore both the user and the target's stat changes when calculating the average.

Comment: Could have sworn I looked through Bulba before posting. My mistake